# Configure tomcat 7 with netbeans on ubuntu

Tags: tomcat, java

How can i configure tomcat 7 to work with netbeans. Looking around various forums, it appears ubuntu has an unusual installation pattern, but i cant find a definitive answer as to how i can get it work with netbeans. Im attempting to add the server like this:

[image: Tomcat config]

but as you can see, its not working properly. Ive installed the default tomcat7 from the repositories. Basically, what do i need to put as the values for catalina_home and catalina_base in order to get it to work?

Im using ubuntu 11.10 x64.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371059/error-registering-a-tomcat-7-server-in-netbeans-7-catalinahomefolderisnotv) will help.

You need to link some of the directories since Netbeans thinks you're using an older version of Tomcat. In my experience, the accepted answer does not work, I needed to do:

```
cd /usr/share/tomcat7
sudo mkdir common
cd common
sudo ln -s ../lib lib
```

I also had a problem where it could not read server-config.xml, which I got after the first error was fixed. To solve this I did:

```
cd /usr/share/tomcat7
sudo mkdir conf 
cd conf
sudo ln -s /etc/tomcat7/server.xml server.xml
sudo chmod o+rx /usr/share/tomcat7/conf
```

This will serve netbeans with an older dir/file structure it expects.

Comment: From nickb answer, you should advance to make a tomcat-users.xml at your /usr/share/tomcat7/conf folder. You can just copy the one you got at /etc/tomcat7/ folder. Works for me.

Comment: Wouldn't symlinking them be a better idea?  That way both files always have the same contents.  Also, why do you feel the need to provide a second copy of nickb's answer?  Better to spend your time answering questions that don't already have an adequate answer.

Comment: Please note that this is a huge security risk. There's a reason these files are not readable for a user, they contain passwords.